# How to colour text in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Given a Windows Forms application with a label:

```
label18 = new Label();
label18.Text = "Installed and started";
this.Controls.Add(label18);
```

How do you set the colour?

Comment: I like how everyone picked red as their example color

Comment: @Chris - Exactly what I was about to post. Psychologists would have a field day!

Comment: @keyboardP: my thoughts exactly!

Comment: C'mon guys, be nice to the new guy.

Comment: Windows Forms or Web Forms or WPF or What?

Comment: @Chris: Everyone knows that [red is the least random colour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/17_(number)).

Comment: Why all the downvotes? Just because it's simple to _you_, doesn't mean that any new .net user should know how to do this!

Comment: @configurator: the downvotes are probably due to the lack of effort that went into asking the question, not due to how simple the question was.

Comment: @configurator: Yup - look at the descriptions *in Visual Studio* for the first few properties and there you have it. I can't believe so many people upvoted this question, it's horrible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
label18.ForeColor = Color.Red;
```

for red forecolor or

```
label18.BackColor = Color.Blue;
```

for blue backcolor.

Answer (score 1):

```
 label18.ForeColor = Color.Red;
```

For red, for example.